# Control de tiempo de inactividad en ventanas diferentes con PHP y Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

He estado investigando acerca del cierre de sesiones por inactividad en mi página, lo he logrado con el siguiente código en mi página principal (*index.php*):

**script**

```
<script>
function idleLogout() {
    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer; // catches touchscreen presses
    window.onclick = resetTimer;     // catches touchpad clicks
    window.onscroll = resetTimer;    // catches scrolling with arrow keys
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function logout() {
        window.location.href = 'logout.php';
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(logout,140000);  // time is in milliseconds
    }
}
idleLogout();
</script>
```

**y paso la función en body a index.php**

```html
<body onunload="idleLogout()">
```

**logout.php (destruyo la sesión)**

```
<?php
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header( "Location:session_expire.php" );
 ?>
```

Pero mi *index.php* tiene funcionalidades que se abren en VENTANAS NUEVAS, entonces, cuando dejo de interactuar en *index.html* porque estoy en esas VENTANAS, ¿qué hacer para que este tiempo de sesión se resetee? ya que se cierra mi sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer, es, cuando pase cierto tiempo, chequear si la ventana del navegador (tu `index.php` en este caso) está o no activa; sería algo asi

```
var window_focus;

$(window).focus(function() {
//Retorna true si index.php está en foco
    window_focus = true;
})
    .blur(function() {
//false en caso contrario
        window_focus = false;
    });
```

Podrías chequearlo de la siguiente manera;

```js
var window_focus;

$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
})
    .blur(function() {
        window_focus = false;
    });

  $(document).one('click',function() {
    setInterval(function() { console.log('en foco? ' + window_focus); }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
Click para empezar<br>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-fNXJFIlca05BIO2Y5zh1xrShK3ME+/lYZ0j+ChxX2DA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Base la respuesta en un la de **user113716** en [StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479734/javascript-jquery-test-if-window-has-focus)

Saludos!

Comment: si entiendo la funcionalidad, pero me queda duda en cómo ejecutarla, tendría que condicionar si es false entonces se ejecuta mi función? aun que también ahí me surge otra duda, qué pasa cuando la ventana no está activa y comienza el temporizador de inactividad, ya que el foco esta en falso.